# Can you restrict Google Sheet to editing just text with restrictions on formatting?

Tags: google-sheets

I simply do not want people who edit the sheet to mess up the formatting. I'm sharing a file with well over fifty people, and if someone messes up the document, it'll probably set off a chain.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

At this time range & sheet protection of Google Sheets doesn't protect formating.

## Alternatives

### Split data entry from data presentation.

#### Use a Google Form

Using a Google Form could be the easiest way to get information from a large number of users.

#### Use a spreadsheet

You could use one sheet or spreadsheet where you allow collaborators to edit cell contents and another sheet for presentation purposes where you pull the cell values from the first sheet by using formulas.

### Reaply format automatically

Use Google Apps Script (GAS) to apply cell format automatically. You could trigger this by using a menu, an event, like onOpen() or a time based trigger.

## References

[Protect a range or sheet from being edited - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/144687?hl=en)